# How to get Siri Suggested playlist/song above Now playing for Music apps like Apple music and Resso when airpods are connected

Tags: ios, swift, siri, mpnowplayinginfocenter, airpods

[image: Now playing Screenshot when Airpods are connected]

When Airpods are connected and there is no music already playing Siri suggests a playlist/songs above the Now Playing widget for the Apple Music app & Resso.

This is probably due to Siri's "Show When listening" suggestions as when I turn it off then it doesn't come any longer.

I have also tried this in my project by donating songs and suggesting songs. But still, it is not coming for me. The code that I have used is below:

```
var inImage: INImage?
 
if let cResource = ImageTask.sharedTask.cachedResource(item: song, requiredType: ImageType.small, thumborUrlForRequiredType: nil, lookOnDisk: true) {
    let imageData = cResource.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9)
    inImage = INImage(imageData: imageData!)
}

let item = INMediaItem(identifier: song.id, title: song.title, type: .song, artwork: inImage, artist: song.artistTitle)
let intentItem = INPlayMediaIntent(mediaContainer: item)
let set = NSOrderedSet(array: [intentItem])

INUpcomingMediaManager.shared.setSuggestedMediaIntents(set)
           
let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intentItem, response: nil)
interaction.groupIdentifier = "in.myapp"
interaction.donate { (error) in
     if error != nil {
       Log.logDebug(message: "&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*: failure, \(String(describing: intent.mediaContainer?.title))")
     }else {
       Log.logDebug(message: "&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*: success, \(String(describing: intent.mediaContainer?.title))")
     }
 }
```

Comment: you can use MPNowPlayingInfoCenter